# fabric js canvas getting duplicated (after continous drag )

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs

i see unexpected error while adding object to canvas i see duplicated object created some where on page .this problem occurs only in when object are dragged into droppable area continously

i am stucked up and could not find solution

complete code :http://liveweave.com/f9z1Bq

what i think

1: when object is dragged continously on to canvas
a:when i drag first object to canvas object and is not reverted at all and 2 nd object also dragged then 1st object gets stucked on to canvas with below errors in console

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'alt' of null :Script stops
or
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tittle ' of null :Script stops
and first object can not be used also

or abc.com/alldevice/undefined 404 (Not Found)

2: i think some time drag event unable to get object when dragged fast or ??..

please help me how to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See link here

[fabric js canvas getting duplicated (after continous drag )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27102086/fabric-js-canvas-getting-duplicated-after-continous-drag#autocomment42969907)

```
 var image =$draggedImage&& $draggedImage.src
```

to

```
$draggedImage = ui.draggable.find("img").get(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

See the following code, you have to go accordingly
**EDIT : see this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/5190m4Lw/**

```
fabric.Image.fromURL('/assets/pug.jpg', function (img) {
    var img1 = img.scale(0.1).set({ left: 100, top: 100 });

    fabric.Image.fromURL('/assets/pug.jpg', function (img) {
        var img2 = img.scale(0.1).set({ left: 175, top: 175 });

        fabric.Image.fromURL('/assets/pug.jpg', function (img) {
            var img3 = img.scale(0.1).set({ left: 250, top: 250 });

            canvas.add(new fabric.Group([img1, img2, img3], { left: 200, top: 200 }))
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I have not made object of group and you have made it, moreover you have not defined object as `var group`. you have directly given `group = ...`.
If possible than also give other name to the object of group. it may conflict with some other keyword

Comment: i want to use group later on so i gave it name

Comment: will doing that solve problem , renamed it to group1 still same issue

Comment: please provide me working fiddle and i will let you know where the problem is

Comment: See i have updated my answer and attaching my code in working situation just have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$drop.droppable({
    over: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    },
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var image =$draggedImage&& $draggedImage.src;
```

to

```
$drop.droppable({
        over: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        },
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $draggedImage = ui.draggable.find("img").get(0);
```